# ClickOnce not showing notifications, but regular exe is

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application. When I install it on the machine it doesn't show the BalloonTipText that I send through the NotifyIcon. However when I go to the ClickOnce application folder and go directly to the .exe itself and load it manually all notifications appear fine.

I have even commented out code to ensure my code was not causing things to go awry. The notifications will not load at all.

When running the following code:

```
notifyTray.ShowBalloonTip(15000, "Title", "Test", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

The notify appears in all settings except the ClickOnce

Comment: Have you applied icons for your project and the forms which show Baloontip?

Comment: Yes, icons show up in tray and in taskbar and anywhere else icons should be shown.

Comment: Can u see any difference between your icons when launched using .exe and clickonce?

Comment: I mean. Icon on taskbar for the form

Comment: Nope, they show up the same, as well as in task  manager.

Comment: Have you assigned icon to the notifyTray?

Comment: Yep, though I should add, this seems to only be happening on Windows 10 (though I don't see how that would cause this weird issue). That starting with the Click Once does not show notifications, even though starting it manual by the exe works fine.